# Python debugging error and split now working

Tags: python, file, debugging, error-handling

```
file = open("teszt.txt", "r")      #opening the file

number_of_lines = 0

for line in file:                   #counts the lines that start with 2021/
    line = line.strip("\n")
    words = line.split()
    if line[:5] == "2021/":
        number_of_lines += 1

for x in file:

    x = file.split()

    print(x)
        
#print("Number of lines, start with 2021: ", number_of_lines)        

from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active

text = "2021/03/01 08:28:22"
date = 1

while date <= number_of_lines:       #writes the texts into cells
    ws[f'A{date}'] = f'{text}'
    date += 1

file.close()
wb.save("teszt.xlsx")
```

When I am trying to debug it just gives me this error:
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'teszt.txt'
but when I am running the code nothing goes wrong.

The other thing is when I am trying to use split() it just doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `split` "just doesn't work"?

Comment: Is 'teszt.txt' in the same directory as the script?